# erlang list lines from position from end of the file

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to have a function that will return x lines of file from the end? The function will take parameter defining how far from end we want to read from(in lines measure) and how much lines we want to be returned from that position:

```
get_lines_file_end(IoDevice, LineNumberPositionFromEnd, LineCount) ->
```

Example:
We have file with 30 lines 0-29

```
get_lines_file_end(IoDevice, -10, 10) // will return lines 20-29
get_lines_file_end(IoDevice, -20, 10) // will return lines 10-19
```

The problem in this is that I can seek only with file:position by certain number of bytes ..

Purpose:
View large log file(hundreds of MB) in page manner starting from last "page".
Erlang is used for rest api which is used by javascript web.

The usage of such function is to view whole log files page by page, where page is represented by x lines of text. No processing of log files, or getting certain information of it is needed.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: the question is - how can I get x lines of text with given position of file, but with listing them from the end of the file.. I see I need to simplify the text in question..

Comment: @AdamLindberg ok I completly restructured the question and simplified to one question..

Comment: @otopolsky: You should keep remarks about size of file and purpose for usage in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points to be made:

1. To make this efficient you must create metadata about your text file contents to amortize the work involved. This way you can directly skip to the bits you need by seeking using `file:position/2` *after* you have created this metadata.
2. If this is your use case then you should be partitioning the work differently. The huge text files should either be broken down into smaller text files, or (more likely) you shouldn't be using text files at all. Depending on what your goal is (which you haven't mentioned; I strongly suspect this is to be an X-Y problem) you probably *don't want text at all* but rather *want to know something represented by the text*. It may be a good idea to keep the raw text around somewhere just in case, but for actual processing of the data is is almost certainly a better idea to create symbolic data that (much more briefly) represents whatever you find interesting about the data, and store that in a database where seeking, scanning, indexing and doing whatever other things you might want are natural operations.

To build metadata about the files, you will need to do something analogous to:

```
1> {ok, Data} = file:read_file("TheLongDarkTeaTimeOfTheSoul.txt").
{ok,<<"Douglas Adams. The Long Dark Tea-Time of the Soul\r\n\r\n"...>>}
2> LineEnds = binary:matches(Data, <<"\r\n">>).                   
[{49,2},
 {51,2},
 {53,2},
 {...}|...]
```

And then save `LineEnds` somewhere separately as meta about the file itself. Using this seeking within the file data is elementary (as in, use `file:position/2` with the data at linebreak X, or at `length(LineEnds) - X` or whatever).

But this is still silly.

If you want to hop around within log files, and especially if you want to be able to locate patterns within them, count certain aspects of them, etc. then you would almost certainly do better reading them into a database like Postgres line by line, counting the line numbers as you go. At that point, pagination becomes a trivial issue.

Log files, however, are usually full of the sort of data that is best represented by symbols, not actual text, and it is probably an even better idea to tokenize the log file. Consider the case of access log files. A repeating number of visitors access from a finite number of access points (IPs, or devices, or whatever) an arbitrary number of times. Each aspect of this can be separately indexed and compared *rather trivially* within a database. The tokenization itself is rather trivial as well. Not only is this solution *much* faster when it comes to later analysis of the data, but it lends itself naturally to answering otherwise *very difficult* to answer questions about the contents of the data in a very straightfoward and familiar manner. ...And you don't even have to lose any of the raw data, or intermediate stages of processing (which may all be independently useful in different ways).

Also... note that all of the above work can be made parallel very easily in Erlang. Whatever your computing resource situation is, writing a solution that best leverages your hardware is certainly within grasp (assuming you have enough total data that this is even an issue).

Just like many "How to do X with data Y?" questions, the real answer is always going to revolve around "What is your goal regarding the data and why?"

Comment: hi, thanks for exhausting answer, I like the idea of indexing the newlines and/or tokenization of particular information. I was expecting the answer that it cannot be done. With some sort of background continuous processing of newlines this may work. I just tried to execute the :matches on 400MB file and it took 10minutes of processing and didnt finished - it ate like 4GB of RAM and started swapping so I turend it off.. but hope that it will work

Comment: @otopolsky If your files are so large I would recommend writing a little loader program to read these into a database, one row per line to start with, storing some metadata as you go (what file it was, and what line). From there you can do whatever you want *much* more easily than directly loading 400MB + gobs of tokenized data into a VM just to pull out a certain segment.

Comment: @otopolsky Hi again, you needing a way to do this in constant space bothered me... so I slapped together a (very ugly, but functional) demonstration of how this could be done in constant space, and it runs on this crappy laptop in 14 seconds in a few hundred megs (I think, didn't check too carefully). Too ugly to paste above, so [here's a link](http://zxq9.com/archives/1056). Hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: ok thanks, I wil give your code a try.. I am little bit beginner, but I think I got the point(process in junks and index the new lines in junk remembering the position etc), can you please put the link inside the answer so that maybe someone will find it? why dont you put the code here I do not understand :)

Comment: @otopolsky I wrote that while drinking, so I didn't try very hard to make it pretty. I'll have to check my post to see what it looks like. I *do* remember basically what it does: it scans forward in the file, pre-loading a chunk at a time to use constant space reading the file; the only real memory growth is in the construction of the list it returns (which is pretty huge). I remember it being way faster than reading it all in. My whole point was to demonstrate for you a technique of reading a huge file in constant space; I'll be happy if I succeeded. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`file:read_line/1` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_line-1) to read lines, discarding those that doesn't match your range:

```erlang
get_lines(File, From) when From > 0 ->
    get_lines(File, file:read_line(File), From, 1).

get_lines(_File, eof, _From, _Current) ->
    [];
get_lines(File, {ok, _Line}, From, Current) when Current < From ->
    get_lines(File, file:read_line(File), From, Current + 1);
get_lines(File, {ok, Line}, From, Current) ->
    [Line|get_lines(File, file:read_line(File), From, Current + 1)];
get_lines(_IoDevice, Error, _From, _Current) ->
    Error.
```

Comment: It will be very ineffective for few GB file when last 10 lines needed.

Comment: yes it would be very unefective but thanks.. in my question I mentioned that I need to set position from the end of the file.. is it possible to rewrite this code to read lines backward from the end of the file? it would be better if we could seek somehow, because with bigger variable From the response would take longer and longer